# Alternative for this react code burger ingereidnet add app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Hi Guys I am new in react i am creating one burger builder app for practice i don't undestand the following code, can any one give the simple alternative for this code?

```
    props.ingredients: {
            salad: 0,
            eggs: 0,
            cheese: 0,
            meat: 0
        },


let ingredientList = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
    .map(igKey => {
        return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
            return <BurgerFilling key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />
        });
    })
    .reduce((rootArray, currEl) => {
        console.log('rootArray>>>', rootArray, currEl);
        return rootArray.concat(currEl);
    }, []);
```

Comment: You need  to provide information on what props.ingredients loop like. What you want the sample output to be.

Comment: please check question again i have modify

Answer (score 0):

Since props.ingredients is an object and each entry within it is just a number, you can simply map over keys of the object and render it without the need for inner map

```
let ingredientList = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
    .map((igKey, i) => {
        return <BurgerFilling key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />
    })
```

Comment: actually my code is working fine i am just want to another way for doing same thing.

Comment: The above code will work for your data and is simpler

Comment: It won't work for non-zero values in the object because for each non-zero value of any particular ingredient, that many`BurgerFilling` components are created. For example, if `salad: 2`, then 2 `BurgerFilling` components should be created

Comment: @Yousaf Depends on what the requirement of other person is

Comment: Thanks @shubhamkhatri. Thanks for you time and answer.